# What is the 'prAchinAgra Kusha' ? Does it loosely indicate the ice age?

Tags: mahabharata

Maharshi Vaishampayana says to King Janmejaya,

> O Janamejaya! As long as Prachinabarhi remained on earth, *prachinagra kusha* covered the surface of the earth.

Source: Hari Vamsha Chapter 2, BORI Mahabharata CE English translation by Dr Bibek Debroy

https://archive.org/stream/TheMahabharata_201808/The%20Mahabharata_djvu.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verse your  have quotes is found in [**Harivamsa purana**](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/hv_1_2.html) -Khila Bhaga -Chapter 2  of   -Verse 31 -of Mahabharata. Your enquiry is about whether this verse loosely indicate Ice-Age.

The answer is **No**. there is no  faint indication of ice age or ice being covered on earth in that verse . In fact the verse is telling us that at the time of Prajapati Prachinbarhi the earth was widely covered in Kusha Grass.  Let us see the translations and what actually the meaning of the verse is  .

> [image]
>
> **prAcIna agrAH kushAH** tasya pR^ithivyAM janamejaya |
>  prAcInabarhir
>   bhagavAn pR^ithivI-tala-cAriNaH ||1-2-31 ||
>
> Oh, janamejaya, when the sacred grass is spread on earth with their
>   **tips pointing to east** in his vedic-rituals, that grass looked like
>   sprawling on whole of the earth, indicating the wideness of his sway
>   on earth, and hence he is known as godly prAchIna-brahi.

---

The subsequent  verses are related to prajapati Prachinbarhi and his kingcraft. Once the Prachinbarhi conducted a Yajna and the kusha grass was laid down in the yajna and that Kusha grass was abandonedly was present on the surface of the earth at that time. The verse actually telling us that why Prajapati  Prachinbarhi is called so, just because the kusha grass which was  Prachinagra - (pointing towards east)  was all over the earth , which the prajapati used in his yajna.

Here is some more [**explanation.**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rpVTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=prachinagra&source=bl&ots=h1AnUhL6Hy&sig=ACfU3U2vM4c50U0yl7cv98jbOQN4QGhhNA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL072jjrbjAhVUVXwKHfcVBMMQ6AEwBnoECBAQAQ#v=onepage&q=prachinagra&f=false)

So the verses does not loosely indicate the ice age.The meaning of the word prachinagra kusha is that the kusha grass facing eastwards. **PrachiNagra = Tip facing east side and kusha =name of the grass.**